# how to delete and keep latest entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am working on a problem where i have table A with columns :

```
1) Contact number
2) name
3) address
4) date updated
```

now because there was no primary key defined multiple times record are inserted with same mobile number. I just want to keep the record with latest date update.

Ex:

```
8018725398       Nikhil     Bangalore     22/4/2016
8018725398       Nikhil     Chennai       22/05/2016
8018725398       Nikhil      lucknow      22/06/2016
```

Now i want to keep only last record, not the first two or first n records. There are like thousand of record and 100 of them are repeating. How to do this ?

Comment: so you want to keep highest record per contact number and delete rest of them ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using sql server for migration and originally tables were in MS-Access. So basically i have to make changes in both sql database and mas-access database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your RDBMS, for ANSI-SQL , you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
WITH dups AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contact_Number ORDER BY date_updated DESC) AS duplicate
FROM TableA)

DELETE FROM dups WHERE duplicate>1;
```

Or with `EXISTS()` which should work for all RDBMS :

```
DELETE FROM TableA t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableA s
             WHERE t.contact_number = s.contact_number
               AND t.date_updated < s.date_updated)
```

Comment: That `not exists` version will delete records that aren't dupes.

Comment: @PeterM. Yes, I don't know why I used `NOT_EXISTS()` , I even wrote `EXISTS()` :)

Comment: Works in sql , can it be used with MS-Access as well? I think it doesn't support Exists keyword.

Comment: @NikhilSrivastava https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa217680(v=office.11).aspx -> it says MS-Access support `EXISTS()`

Answer (score 1):

Insert into Your Table

```
Select 
T.Contactnumber,
T.name,
T.address,
TT.Maxdate  
from tableA  T
INNER JOIN (
Select Contactnumber,MAX(dateupdated)Maxdate FROM tableA 
GROUP BY Contact number,name,address)TT
ON T.Contactnumber = TT.Contactnumber
```

Comment: He wants to delete, not select them

Comment: In this query we are selecting all the unique row, we can use this by inserting record in a new table and then delete original records and push this back. I used similar approach, but the limitation is that i cant create any extra table. i somehow have to manipulate and delete data from the same table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT null
    FROM table_a sub
    WHERE a.contact_number = sub.contact_number
    AND a.date_updated < sub.date_updated );
```

Use the above to check that the record set for deletion is what you expect. Then change it to a `DELETE` statement instead of a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

The task is simple: delete records for which exist a later record with the same number.

```
delete from mytable
where exists
(
  select *
  from mytable later
  where later.contact_number = mytable.contact_number
  and later.date_updated > mytable.date_updated
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Sever

```
delete from A  where not exists 
(
    select 1 from 
            ( select [Contact number],max([date updated]) as [date updated] 
             from A 
             group by [Contact number]
            ) as S
where A.[Contact number]=S.[Contact number] 
        and A.[date updated]=S.[date updated]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This select provides you the Records with the last update:

```
select ContactNumber, MAX(DateUpdated) as LastUpdate
    from TableA
    group by ContactNumber
```

It can be used as a subselect to delete the rows, which has the same ContactNumber but a different DateTime-Value:

```
delete from TableA
from
    (select ContactNumber, MAX(DateUpdated) as LastUpdate
        from TableA
        group by ContactNumber) A
where TableA.ContactNumber = A.ContactNumber and DateUpdated != LastUpdate
```